twig urlencodes string, ignoring the raw-filter
First off, I am well aware that twig is server- and JavaScript is client-side.
Still I would like to use twigs path() function to render my JavaScript code and inject the JavaScript variable as a RAW-String, but it gets escaped all the time, and I am curious why the raw-filter does not apply?
I do have the following JavaScript within my twig file (simplified):
// file.html.twig
<script>
print '<a href="{{ path('article_edit', {id: ("' + full['id'] + '"|raw)}) }}">Linktext</a>';
</script>

As the path for article_edit is /articles/{id}/edit I expect twig to do the following two steps:
// Expected twig-render, step 1
<script>
print '<a href="/articles/{id}/edit">Linktext</a>';
</script>

Step 2: {id} then gets replaced with my given string ' + full['id'] + ', resulting in a valid Javascript:
// Expected twig-render, final step
<script>
print '<a href="/articles/' + full['id'] + '/edit">Linktext</a>';
</script>

Which would be rendered on clientside to <a href="/articles/1/edit">Linktext</a>
But still, even though I used the |raw filter, twig does urlencode the string. Resulting in the following output:
// Actual twig-render
<script>
print '<a href="/articles/%27%20+%20full%5B%27id%27%5D%20+%20%27/edit">Linktext</a>';
</script>

The following twig-codes do have all the very same output:
{{ path('article_edit', {id: ("' + full['id'] + '")}) }} // no filter
{{ path('article_edit', {id: ("' + full['id'] + '"|raw)}) }} // filter on the id
{{ path('article_edit', {id: ("' + full['id'] + '")})|raw }} // filter on the function
{{ path('article_edit', {id: ("' + full['id'] + '"|raw)})|raw }} // filter on both id and function

If you still think it is a problem of client- and server-side rendering, I have created a little PHP fiddle to demonstrate the problem and expected behaviour with plain PHP, without twig: https://ideone.com/amZ4T4
Why is twig ignoring the filter and does urlencode the JavaScript? Isn't that what that filter is for, so I could build up a dynamic JavaScript code within twig?
I now use the hard-coded path as a workaround, but I am curious why the filter is ignored...

I've already told you this isn't possible (reference) - The only way to make this work is to use your own custom Twig\Function to generate the "path" - "If you URL's are actually built like that, you shouldn't use the path function and create your own custom twig function" - reference

FWIW: That value get's urlencoded and not escaped btw

And I asked you the question, what do you mean by "URL's built like that"?
That is a perfectly fine and common URL in my opinion and I would like to undestand the limits of the raw-filter, which obviously does not work on the path-function.
And point taken, its urlencoding instead of encoding. But still, should the raw-filter prevent from ulencoding?

And I dont see any similarity to the question you mentioned, as there is no encoding or escaping issue at all.

Is this a JS issue or a PHP issue? Does the generated markup look like expected or not?

Its an PHP/twig issue, the actual output is /articles/%27%20+%20full%5B%27id%27%5D%20+%20%27/edit instead of the expected /articles/' + full['id'] + '/edit

No, that's not what filter raw is for - demo. Even if you hack in the url_decode it still won't work the way you want to - demo (src/templates/path.html) - You need to drop the path function provided by Symfony and add your own...

However ... The real solution is just to use the FOSJsRoutingBundle

So, path is running on the server, while the rest of your URL is built in the frontend. How should that work properly?

FYI: This is not a Twig issue. The provided function path is made and maintained by Symfony - "as there is no encoding or escaping issue at all" - Of course there are no decoding issue, the bundle will generate the proper URL and return it. Quite unsure why you refuse to test it out

@NicoHaase - I want to have the javascript created dynamically. This is not any issue in terms of server- and client processing, as proven here, with the expected behaiour in plain php: https://ideone.com/amZ4T4

@DarkBee - So its the expected behaviour of the raw-filter to still urlencode variables? The documentation should be updated then, including this.

You changed the title of the question and I already pointed out in a demo, that even if hack in the urldecode function from PHP in Twig, the result will not be the one you are expecting

raw prevents HTML/JavaScript/etc to be a escaped to HTML entities, which is a different thing than encoding query params - demo

Alright, so the expected output of the raw-filter is just preventing escaping and not encoding? (That would be the answer I was looking for, if that is the case.)


twig urlencodes string, ignoring the raw-filter

Exactly. As it should. As explained in the docs:

The raw filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it:

This filter simply prevents the escaping of HTML entities, in case you want to output them as they are.
E.g. if your output contained <b>bold</bold>, it would be rendered verbatim, instead of as &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;.
Your output is not being escaped at all, so raw does nothing from preventing the escaping of the string. It's a no-op filter in this context.
The string is being URL encoded, as you can see, because it's the output of path(), which is assumed to be a URL and usually something you'd want to encode as a URL.
That's not even controlled by Twig. The path function is defined by the RoutingExtension in the Twig Symfony bridge (here), and the only thing it does is use UrlGeneratorInterface::generate to get the URL, which is returned to the template.
The URL will always be generated URL encoded... because it's a URL. And since no escaping is necessary to print a URL encoded URL, raw does nothing to that output.

I now use the hard-coded path as a workaround, but I am curious why the filter is ignored...

At first sight, this seems like using the wrong tool for the job. The filter is not being ignored, it simply does not do what you think it does.

Thank you very much for the explanation, that was exactly what I am looking for.
I now understand why the filter "isnt working" and this behaviour is not mentioned in the docs at all. Now it all makes sense to me :)

Glad you find it useful. Confusions about what's "escaping", what's "encoding", what's "hashing", etc. happened to all of us at one point or another.

if i understood your problem, you want use js array to set parameter id of your request. In the documentation it's explain you can use pure js to make dynamic url render. Symfony doc. So you can use FosjsRoutingBundle. I use this when i want make ajax/fetch request. It's necessary to configure your symfony controller to expose your path to js with : options=["expose"=>true].
example :
    #[Route(path: '/article/{id}/edit', name: 'article_edit', options: ['expose' => true])]
    public function edit(Article $id)
    {
        return $this->render('article-edit.html.twig');
    }

In js :
    const url = Routing.generate("article_edit", {id: full["id"]});
    const htmlLink = '<a href="' + url + '">Linktext</a>';

I don't know if this solution suits you, but maybe you could look in this direction.

Thank you, I was already using FosjsRoutingBundle, which was the solution to the problem. But this question was to understand why there was a problem in the first place, so I do not run into the same error again. yivi explained everything well in the comment marked as answer :-)
